# increase number automatically in the text field after clicking save button

Tags: javascript

i had a text field named as `bill no` ,My problem is to increase value in the text field automatically , like initially the `bill no` will be 1 , after clicking save button it should save with 1 after saving the `bill no` should automatically increase to 2 ,

any advice ?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Sales</title>
      <link href="css/module.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
         <script src="js/date.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});
        });


      </script>
   </head>
   <body>

      <div class="reg-form">
     <form method="post" name="sales" action="sales">
            <table class="main">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>SALES
                     </th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
            </table>
            <table class="in-sec-small">  
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="label">
                        <label for="patient-type">PATIENT TYPE
                        </label>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <select id="patient_type" class="textfield-form-req-select" type="text" name="patient_type" required>
                           <option value="member">IP</option>
                           <option value="non-member">OP</option>
                            <option value="non-member">WIP</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td class="label">
                        <label for="reg-type">REG TYPE
                        </label>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <select id="reg_type" class="textfield-form-req-select" type="text" name="reg_type" required>
                           <option value="member">Member</option>
                           <option value="non-member">Non Member</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td class="label">
                        <label for="bill-no">BILL NO
                        </label>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input id="bill_no"  class="textfield-form-date-req" type="text" name="bill_no" required>
                     </td>

                  </tr>
```

Comment: no one is there to solve my problem........

Answer (score 0):

Try code below, if you save your bill no through ajax, increase number in your ajax success callback.

```
$("#your-save-button-id").click(function(){
    ... do your save action here ...
    $("#bill_no").val(parseInt($('#bill_no').val()) + 1);
})
```

Comment: i am not using ajax.i don't know how to use it. can u help me with javascript

Comment: then you want to submit the form,then add the add the number? if so you should do this at sever side

Comment: it's not ajax but jquery